# Pyspark + Databricks - Need to join two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, merge, databricks

I need to join two dataframes as follows:

Dataframe1:

| date | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-10 | David |

Dataframe2:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx | Hello |
| 2 | dd | Test |
| 3 | eee | Block |
| 4 | dd | Support |

Dataframe3 = Dataframe1 + Dataframe2

| date | name | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-10 | David | 1 | xxx | Hello |
| 2021-01-10 | David | 2 | dd | Test |
| 2021-01-10 | David | 3 | eee | Block |
| 2021-01-10 | David | 4 | dd | Support |

I tried to do some merges (left & outer) and also the concat but without success. Could you help me to be able to implement this solution?

Comment: Would [crossJoin](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html) help?

Comment: @werner I don't have this lib: . ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.sql.DataFrame' I'm using in Databricks

Comment: There is no needed to import `DataFrame` module, this is the command that @werner was mentioning: `df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2)`

Answer (score 1):

A cross join should do it: [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html)

```
Dataframe3 = Dataframe1.crossJoin(Dataframe2)
```

Result:

```
Dataframe3.collect()
[Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 1, 10), name='David', column1=1, column2='xxx', column3='Hello'),
 Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 1, 10), name='David', column1=2, column2='dd', column3='Test'),
 Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 1, 10), name='David', column1=3, column2='eee', column3='Block'),
 Row(date=datetime.date(2021, 1, 10), name='David', column1=4, column2='dd', column3='Support')]
```

Answer (score 0):

On Databricks:

```
d1 = spark.createDataFrame(dataframe1)
d2 = spark.createDataFrame(dataframe2)

d1.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_d1")
d2.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_d2")


d3 = spark.sql('''select * from vw_d1 CROSS JOIN vw_d2''')
```